# Feathersjs local auth password verification doesn't work

Tags: passport.js, passport-local, feathersjs

I've set the fields:

```
local: { usernameField: 'username', passwordField: 'sha_pass_hash' }
```

and the model like it is supposed to be. Whenever i try to send my payload to the server i only receive *error: (401) Route: /auth/local - Invalid login.*

Now my question is how the password verification works, since i, by no chance, can get this working.

The Password is stored as a sha1 inside the database and i sent the sha1 password as part of the payload.

Why is it not comparing them directly, what exactly does it? I'm just confused.

Answer (score 2):

The default hash comparison is expecting a [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) hashed (+ salted) string (created by the `hashPassword` hook).

If you want to use plain SHA1 hashed passwords you can use [auth 1.0](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/docs/migrating.md) and implement a [custom verifier](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-local#customizing-the-verifier).

Comment: So currently the feathers-authentication module which i just generated yesterday is version: 0.7.11. Do i have to update the package.js file manually to use auth 1.0 or will it brake something?

Comment: No, you have to use the `hashPassword` hook before `create` however otherwise you will store an invalid password in the database.

Comment: @Daff: Btw, How can I declare passwordField in json config file to let feathersjs know which field to compare. My password is stored in `User.services.password.bcrypt`.